# Remove links from the_content when using filters wp_trim_excerpt

Tags: functions, hooks, excerpt, the-content

I'm using wp_trim_excerpt which is working perfectly but I want to strip the links contained in the the_excerpt (using get_the_content), I've looked online and tried many solutions to get the thing to work and hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.

My working code looks like this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_trim_excerpt', 'my_custom_excerpt', 10, 2 );

function my_custom_excerpt($text, $raw_excerpt) {
    if( ! $raw_excerpt ) {
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
        $text = substr( $content, 0, strpos( $content, '</p>' ) + 4 );
    }
    $text = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $text); 
    $buttonmore = '<p><a class="button right" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> Read the full article...</a></p>';
    return $text . " " . $buttonmore;
}
```

Not working (I've added strip_tags( get_the_content() )

```
add_filter( 'wp_trim_excerpt', 'my_custom_excerpt', 10, 2 );

function my_custom_excerpt($text, $raw_excerpt) {
    if( ! $raw_excerpt ) {
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', strip_tags(get_the_content()) );
        $text = substr( $content, 0, strpos( $content, '</p>' ) + 4 );
    }
    $text = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $text); 
    $buttonmore = '<p><a class="button right" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> Read the full article...</a></p>';
    return $text . " " . $buttonmore;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another preg_replace. Something like:

```
$text = preg_replace('/<a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/', "", $text);
```

Comment: Worked an absolute treat! Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Obvious caution needed for a tags without the href attribute as the first element `<a class="xzy" href="abc"`...